# cannot remove auto fill entries in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I am having trouble removing the auto fill entries that appear when the users starts typing in an input box in chrome.I am on a windows machine.

After searching here the proposed solution is to highlight the entry I want to delete and then press **delete** or **shift+delete**.

**Neither of these work.**
What else can I try?

Comment: Under advanced settings > "Privacy", you can uncheck "Use a web service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" if that is what you are referring to. The other setting is the autofill, under advanced settings > "Passwords and forms" uncheck "Enable Autofill to fill out web forms in a single click".

Answer (score 1):

To remove specific inappropriate or embarrassing suggestions:

- Start typing some text
- move up or down with the arrow keys
- click on Shift-Del to remove the selected URL

Answer (score 1):

It's in your bookmark, you have to delete it from your bookmark first.

Comment: Actually this scenario happened to me, solution was delete it from bookmarks

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, you likely need to use `Fn-Shift-Delete`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to delete all of auto fill entries there's option in Google Chrome settings "Clear browsing data"

1. **Settings**
2. **Show advanced settings...** (at the bottom of the page)
3. **Clear browsing data** (in Privacy section)
4. Change "Obliterate the following items from" to **the beginning of time**
5. Mark only **Autofill form data**
6. **Clear browsing data** button

Comment: I do not want to delete all of auto fill entries,only specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

AutoFill and AutoComplete are two different things. AutoFill fills in information in forms. AutoComplete completes URL's when you start to type in the Address bar. The Shift-Del method will not override a Bookmark. You can use CCleaner, Chrome Privacy clearing, etc. None of that will work if it's in your Bookmarks or Favorites. Delete the Bookmark/Favorite.